# Using JSON_EXTRACT or JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR in Presto SQL or Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, presto

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {78kfcX={"Sent": 77, "Respond": 31, "NoResponse": 31}, 97Facz={"Sent": 45, "Respond": 31, "NoResponse": 31}} |
| 333 | {5mdzrZ={"Sent": 1, "Respond": 1, "NoResponset": 1}} |

Given the table above, I am trying to extract the "Sent" value... In cases where there are multiple sent values then I want to take the max.

I have tried using json_extract, json_extract_scalar, json_parse and multiple other functions in SQL but nothing seems to work. I keep getting NULL values in all my attempts.

The expected outcome given the example above should be:

| id | Sent |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 77 |
| 333 | 1 |

I think one way to approach this is by first doing a CROSS JOIN UNNEST to split the value column by 78kfcX, 97Facz, 5mdzrZ ids. And then extracting the sent value from there and taking the max, grouped by the id column.

Attempted code:

```
SELECT 
id, 
json_extract_scalar(value, '$.Sent') AS 'sent'
FROM table
```

JSON_PARSE(value) returns the following error:

> Cannot convert value to JSON: '{78kfcX={"Sent": 77, "Respond": 31, "NoResponse": 31}, 97Facz={"Sent": 45, "Respond": 31, "NoResponse": 31}}'

Comment: what is the `typeof(value)` result? Also please add attempted SQL.

Comment: I tried different methods as explained in the question.

Comment: I've asked to ADD those attempts to the question so we can understand the structure better. Also can you please add result of `select typeof(value) from table`? This will clarify the data type and ease to help you.

Comment: Hi tglacierboy, could you use "select typeof(value) from your_table_name" to confirm the data type of the value column? Based on the return value, we may adjust the answer a bit to fit your input column data type.

Comment: @GuruStron
Thanks for the dialogue so far. I have added some attempted code. Will add the select typeof(value) output once I get my system up and running.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that this - _" I keep getting NULL values in all my attempts."_ statement is  a bit faulty, you are not getting nulls, you are getting exception, at least in some cases. It seems your data is varchar, so the answer provided by @jonathan200 should do the trick.

Comment: @GuruStron just confirming, data is indeed varchar

Comment: @jonathan200 confirmed as 'varchar'

Comment: As it is varchar, you can use the answer below to get the result you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**answer for original question**
The input string itself is not in [JSON format](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp). Therefore, we need to first extract `{"Sent": 77, "Respond": 31, "NoResponse": 31}` out by regular expression, and then apply [JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-functions) function on it.

The following regex pattern can extract the attribute maps out from the input ([Regex101 verification](https://regex101.com/r/o9wxnP/1)):

```
\{".*?\}
```

With alll above tricks, in Presto, you can get the result you want in the following steps:

Step 1. Use [regexp_extract_all()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html) function to extract all attribute maps out of the input string into an array.

Step 2. Apply [JSON_extract_scalar()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json-functions) to each element of the array and extract `Sent` part out

Step 3. Use [array_max()](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html) function to get the max value you want.

Here is the query in Presto:

```
SELECT
    id,
    APPAY_MAX(
         TRANSFORM(
             REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value, '\{".*?\}'),
             v -> CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(v, '$.Sent') AS INT)
         )
   ) AS sent
FROM
    input_table
```

| id | Sent |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 77 |
| 333 | 1 |

**answer for the follow-up**
If we want to calculation sum instead of max from the array, we can use [reduce() function and lamda expression](https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/0.167-t/functions/lambda.html) to do that.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    REDUCE(
         TRANSFORM(
             REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(value, '\{".*?\}'),
             v -> CAST(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(v, '$.Sent') AS INT)
         ), 0, (s,x) -> s + x, s -> s
   ) AS sent
FROM
    input_table
```

| id | Sent |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 122 |
| 333 | 1 |

Comment: I have some doubts that data is varchar, this is usual representation of rows or maps when used in Presto/Trino, hence the question in the comments.

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, the usual representation of maps in Presto is {xxx:yyyy}, while the question example input is xxxx=yyyy, that's not a usual Presto map requestion, neither a valid JASON format. user can cast to varchar for operations if needed.

Comment: Just executed `select map(array[2,1], array['b', 'a']);` in my Trino console and got `{1=a, 2=b}` in the console output.

Comment: _"JASON format"_ - I suppose you have a typo and meant JSON _" user can cast to varchar for operations if needed"_ - 1) not always, not everything can be cast to varchar in Presto/Trino 2) if data is a map there are better approaches then using regexes.

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, I executed the same `select map(array[2,1], array['b', 'a'])` in my Presto client, but I got `{"1":"b","2":"b"}`, I will let the user to confirm. the regex part can change once the user what is the data type of the column. Thanks for your note in advance.

Comment: The problem here that user claims to use `json_extract` and getting null, so since this is not a valid json in the column values and `json_extract` can be used either on varchar or json I wonder what and how exactly is stored there and how it is exactly queried (cause if ty[e/structure mismatch then result should be an error, not null ).

Comment: Hi @GuruStron, for type casting, your comment is valid. so let us wait for the user to confirm the data type of the column, we can change the answer accordingly.

Comment: As for Presto client - do not know which one and how do you use that but in theory it can do some magic changing the representation to more user-friendly. But not an expert here. Worked with Presto/Trino mainly via console or Athena.

Comment: As for type casting - casting maps to json can do some magic =)

Comment: @jonathan200 Thanks for the solution. If I want to find the SUM instead of MAX, how would I go about this? ARRAY_SUM doesn't work on Trino/Presto it seems

Comment: Hi @tglacierboy, you can use reduce and lamda expression to calculate sum in that case. I have updated my answer to include the follow up query for calculating sum in the last section.