# Using JSON_EXTRACT or JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR in Spark SQL or Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Based on this exact question I asked in the past: [Using JSON_EXTRACT or JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR in Presto SQL or Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75670046/17678500)

I am looking for a solution in Spark SQL or Scala.

Here's the question (same as the link):

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | {78kfcX={"Sent": 77, "Respond": 31, "NoResponse": 31}, 97Facz={"Sent": 45, "Respond": 31, "NoResponse": 31}} |
| 333 | {5mdzrZ={"Sent": 1, "Respond": 1, "NoResponset": 1}} |

Given the table above, I am trying to extract the "Sent" value... In cases where there are multiple sent values then I want to find the sum.

The value column is a varchar.

The expected outcome given the example above should be:

| id | sent |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 122 |
| 333 | 1 |

```
// input DataFrame
val data = Seq(
  (123, "{78kfcX={\"Sent\": 77, \"Respond\": 31, \"NoResponse\": 31}, 97Facz={\"Sent\": 45, \"Respond\": 31, \"NoResponse\": 31}}"),
  (333, "{5mdzrZ={\"Sent\": 1, \"Respond\": 1, \"NoResponset\": 1}}")
).toDF("id", "value")

// Define UDF to extract and sum numMessagesSent from JSON
val extractNumMessagesSent = udf((inputStr: String) => {
  import scala.util.matching.Regex
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

  val pattern = new Regex("(?<=\\{)(\".*?\": \\d+)(?=,)")
  val sentPairs = pattern.findAllIn(inputStr).toList
  val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
  sentPairs.map { sentPair =>
    val cleanedJsonStr = "{" + sentPair + "}"
    val jsonObj = mapper.readTree(cleanedJsonStr)
    jsonObj.get("Sent").asInt
  }.sum
})

// Apply the UDF to the input DataFrame
val result = (testdata
  .withColumn("num_messages", extractNumMessagesSent(col("value"))))

result.show()
```

This is what I have tried in scala and it works.. but I am looking for a cleaner and shorter way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

[The from_json spark column method may help](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-from_json-convert-json-column-to-struct-map-or-multiple-columns-2/)

First you'll have to parse JUST the JSON portion of your value strings out e.g. (`{\"Sent\": 77, \"Respond\": 31, \"NoResponse\": 31}`), then you can `from_json()` the parsed JSON string column, and start referencing it as you would any JSON in spark...

Maybe remove all the xxxxxx= portions of the value strings, and wrap each one with [] before parsing arrays of those three column structs...